# From essential oscillation to a continuous representative

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $u$ be a measurable function such that for **every**(former: a.e.) $x\in \Omega$ there holds for sequences $R_n,\delta_n\to 0$  that$$\omega_n:=ess-osc_{B_{R_n}(x)} u\leq \delta_n. \tag{1}$$
Edit: Usually one has $$\delta_n =\sigma(\omega_{n-1})\ \omega_{n-1}$$
for $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$
How can one show that there is a continuous represenative?

What have i tried?
Let $\{x_k\}\subset \Omega$ be the set (countable would even suffice) where (1) holds. It is dense in $\Omega$ by assumption. My problem is now how to define the function in the remaining points:

In particular, let $x_k\to x_0$. I (think) Iwant to show that $u(x_k)$ is a Cauchy-sequence, but I don't have boundedness to get to a subsequence. And even if I had this, I don't see (yet) how to show that the limit is independent of the sequence since $(1)$ does not necessarily hold in $x_0$.
Any hints?

Comment: Do you mean "a representative that is continuous a.e."? You can't have everywhere continuity with this assumption. Consider $u(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So, the problem in my assumption is, that I assumed the essential oscillation converge to 0 only a.e., right? What if $(1)$ holds for every $x\in \Omega$?